# JQuery accordian doesn't work inside a function with dynamic data

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

In my asp.mvc project i have below view file. I am getting accordian data through WEB API call, format it wil "div","p" tags and able to append to existing div tag, "accapis". At the end when i tried to used ("#idaccapis").accordion(); and it is throwing an error,  "object doesn't support this property or method 'accordion'. Please help me with what i'm missing or doing wrong.

I don't think there is any problem with script inclusion since if i put a static content then ("#idaccapis").accordion() is working fine.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = ">Help";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Web API Help</h2> 
    <div class="accapis" id="idaccapis"> 
    </div> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/api/Help",
                    function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            $('<h3/>', { text: val.ControllerName }
                            ).appendTo('.accapis');
                                    $('<div />', { "class":     
val.ControllerName }).appendTo            ($('.accapis'));
                            $.each(val.Path, function (k, v) {
                                $('<p/>', { text: v }).appendTo($("." + val.ControllerName));
                            });
                        });
                    })
                    .complete(function () {
                        alert($("#idaccapis").html()); //able to see the html generated, they     look fine
                        $("#idaccapis").accordion(); //ERROR
                    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you load jquery-ui _before_ this script runs.

Comment: I have added jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js in my _layout.cshtml file. As i have mentioned earlier i have static content, accordian is working fine.